# How to stop my letterhead from increasing dinbrief top margin?

Tags: positioning, letterhead, dinbrief

I have a letterhead macro created with tikz that I'm using with *dinbrief* but it pushes the entire content of the letter down by 15mm.  This would not be a big deal but when I print it out it no longer positions the address properly for DIN standard envelopes with an address window. The fold lines on the left side should be 105 and 210mm from the top, respectively.

Here is a minimal example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\briefkopf{
%header
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        %\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (10cm, 8cm);
        \draw[line width=0.1cm, color=red] (0, 7cm) --(15cm, 7cm);
        \node[above right] at (15cm, 5.5cm) {\Huge{\textbf{Prof. Dr. Dr.}}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\signature{Prof. Dr. Dr. Billiam Bohegas}
\place{Popeldorf}
\address{\briefkopf}
\date{\today\hspace*{31 mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Bob Derp \\ Herp GmbH \\ Alexanderstrasse 3 \\ 10178 Berlin \\ Germany }
  \opening{Dear Bob}

  Lorem ipsum ominus dominus etc.

  \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not dead-set on using dinbrief.  It's a bit old but I do like that it prints the fold lines and positions the address for standard envelopes.  I am open to using any other classes as long as they can do those two things.

Comment: If I don't pass your `\briefkopf` macro to `\address`, the output doesn't seem any lower than when I leave it. What exactly do you mean by "shoves my whole letter down the page a bit"? Could you perhaps post a screenshot or two to show us the difference you observe?

Comment: I added an image.  Indeed, if I take out the letterhead tikz part completely, it still is vertically indented 15mm too far.  Could this be a side effect of using XeLaTeX?

Comment: @BrendanHowell I observed this issue also with LuaLaTeX. But also, when I leave out the `\fontspec` line and compile with PDFLaTeX, nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Load `a4paper` as a class option instead of loading `geometry`

Loading `geometry` with option `a4paper` inside a `dinbrief` document seems to cause the undesirable behaviour you report. However, according to subsection 4.8 of the the `dinbrief` class documentation, there are class options for specifying the paper size. The problem goes away (at least with XeLaTeX) if you don't load `geometry` but pass `a4paper` as a class option instead.

### Side note

I've modified your `briefkopf` macro a bit. Nesting a `tikzpicture` in another's node in order to achieve a particular shift is sort of awkward. Instead, you can use the `tikz` library called `calc`, which allows you to perform arithmetic calculations on nodes and achieve the placement you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{dinbrief}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\briefkopf{%
%header
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[line width=0.1cm, color=red]
            ($(current page.north west)+(0cm,0cm)$) -- ++(15cm, 0cm);
        \node[above right] at ($(current page.north west)+(15cm,-1.5cm)$)
            {\Huge{\textbf{Prof. Dr. Dr.}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\signature{Prof. Dr. Dr. Billiam Bohegas}
\place{Popeldorf}
\address{\briefkopf}
\date{\today\hspace*{31 mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Bob Derp \\ Herp GmbH \\ Alexanderstrasse 3 \\ 10178 Berlin \\ Germany }
  \opening{Dear Bob}

  Lorem ipsum ominus dominus etc.

  \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The fold lines are still wrong but this answer solves my issue with pushing the recipient address down the page.  I think I will add a bit of tikz to fake it.